# How to manually set a blank space in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I would like to know how to **manually** set a blank space. Note these double quotes inside the text. Is there something **in Flutter** that would have the same effect as these double quotes?

I would like to do something like this

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) => NextPage(
           result: (something + '' + other_thing) // This '' doesn't work in Flutter
```

Comment: your `print` statement gives `Foo + '' + Foo` on stdout, is it really what you want? if so use the exactly same `print("Foo + '' + Foo");` in dart/flutter

Comment: Hi @pskink, I edited the question above. I want a space between the `something` and `other_thing`. I tried using SizedBox() but it didn't work.

Comment: sorry i dont know what you want to achieve with concatenating empty string like `''`, for example: `print('foo' + '' + 'bar'); print('foo' + ' ' + 'bar');` - run it on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ for example - what the first print is supposed to do?

Comment: https://github.com/viguinijpv/my_proj/blob/main/lib/home.dart   --> You can go to line 59. All the way down I commented where it should have a blank space inside `result`

Comment: The comments are `//Right here it should have a blank space`

Comment: Should I write this inside `result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) => NextPage(
           result: ('$something $other_thing')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible. If it's a recurrent task for you,  you can create a function for it.

```dart
String setBlankSpace(String a, String b){
 return "$a $b";
}
```